# How to validate uploaded file size with Joi

Tags: validation, hapi.js, joi

I'm using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate requests. I'm wondering how should I validate uploaded file size with Joi.

I'm sending many files as a stream.

Comment: What does validating a file size mean? You want to limit the max, or you're expecting an exact size?

Comment: @MattHarrison I'm expecting the max limit.

Comment: Is it enough to limit payload maxBytes? Or you want a per-file limit? https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route-options (see maxBytes)

Comment: @MattHarrison: per file limit is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To limits the size of incoming payloads to the specified byte count you can use as follow:

```
route.options.payload.maxBytes
```

for example:

```
      payload: {
          maxBytes: 20715200,
          output: 'stream',
          parse: true,
          allow: 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      validate: {
          payload: {
                bannerImage: Joi.any()
                .meta({swaggerType: 'file'})
                .optional()
                .allow('')
                .description('image file'),
                   },
          failAction: UniversalFunctions.failActionFunction
      },
```

- Default value will be 1048576 (1MB).
- Allowing very large payloads may cause the server to run out of memory.